# ion-scroll doesn't scroll vertically

Tags: ionic-framework

so i have added 2 ion-scroll on my page.
example code is here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNNExR

the first ion-scroll works properly, i can scroll left-right.

for the second ion-scroll, where there are lots of 'test' paragraphs.I cant scroll vertically (top - bottom). It always bounces back once i scorll a bit further than the screen height.

note: i didnt set height to the ion-scroll or the content inside the ion-scroll as the height is not fixed (eg: ion-scroll height depends on screen size, should fill the rest of screen height and content height depends on content length)

what did i do wrong? thanks.

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <title>Ionic vertical and horizontal Scroll</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
      <h1 class="title">Ionic vertical and horizontal Scroll</h1>
     </ion-header-bar>

<ion-pane>
    <ion-content>
<div>
            <ion-scroll zooming="false" direction="x" scrollbar-x="false" scrollbar-y="false" has-bouncing="true" style="width: 100%;">
            123
            </ion-scroll>
    </div>

<div>
<ion-scroll zooming="false" direction="y" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
</ion-scroll>
</div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-pane>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

added this in your controller with `$ionicScrollDelegate`, `$timeout` injector:

```
 $timeout(function(){
    //return false; // <--- comment this to "fix" the problem
    var sv = $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('horizontal').getScrollView();

    var container = sv.__container;

    var originaltouchStart = sv.touchStart;
    var originalmouseDown = sv.mouseDown;
    var originaltouchMove = sv.touchMove;
    var originalmouseMove = sv.mouseMove;

    container.removeEventListener('touchstart', sv.touchStart);
    container.removeEventListener('mousedown', sv.mouseDown);
    document.removeEventListener('touchmove', sv.touchMove);
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', sv.mousemove);


    sv.touchStart = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault = function(){}
      originaltouchStart.apply(sv, [e]);
    }

    sv.touchMove = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault = function(){}
      originaltouchMove.apply(sv, [e]);
    }

    sv.mouseDown = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault = function(){}
      originalmouseDown.apply(sv, [e]);
    }

    sv.mouseMove = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault = function(){}
      originalmouseMove.apply(sv, [e]);
    }

    container.addEventListener("touchstart", sv.touchStart, false);
    container.addEventListener("mousedown", sv.mouseDown, false);
    document.addEventListener("touchmove", sv.touchMove, false);
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", sv.mouseMove, false);
  });
  $timeout(function(){
    //return false; // <--- comment this to "fix" the problem
    var sv = $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('horizontal2').getScrollView();

    var container = sv.__container;

    var originaltouchStart = sv.touchStart;
    var originalmouseDown = sv.mouseDown;
    var originaltouchMove = sv.touchMove;
    var originalmouseMove = sv.mouseMove;

    container.removeEventListener('touchstart', sv.touchStart);
    container.removeEventListener('mousedown', sv.mouseDown);
    document.removeEventListener('touchmove', sv.touchMove);
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', sv.mousemove);


    sv.touchStart = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault = function(){}
      originaltouchStart.apply(sv, [e]);
    }

    sv.touchMove = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault = function(){}
      originaltouchMove.apply(sv, [e]);
    }

    sv.mouseDown = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault = function(){}
      originalmouseDown.apply(sv, [e]);
    }

    sv.mouseMove = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault = function(){}
      originalmouseMove.apply(sv, [e]);
    }

    container.addEventListener("touchstart", sv.touchStart, false);
    container.addEventListener("mousedown", sv.mouseDown, false);
    document.addEventListener("touchmove", sv.touchMove, false);
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", sv.mouseMove, false);
  });
```

Comment: So what does this do? Posting just code is usually not all that helpful; posting an *explanation* usually is!

Comment: add this code in your controller ,ionic developer  know this

Comment: That is not an explanation.